# Matching labels in a Visual Studio Code grammar

Tags: visual-studio-code, grammar, textmate

I have this pattern in my language.json repository.

```
"labels": {
        "patterns": [
            {
                "match": "^(\\w+:)$",
                "captures": {
                    "1": {
                        "name": "labels.control.uat"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

It is failing to match a label, e.g. `TYPEPARAMOK:` where that is the only content of a line.

I know that the rest of the grammar is OK since if I change the regex, it matches so I am pretty sure the regex is the problem but in all of my regex testing, it works.  Just not here.

Comment: what happens if you use the regex: `TYPEPARAMOK:`